# NavigationController does not reload tableView data after popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift, tableview

Sorry for my english

In my app, i have a login form. If the username and password are good, 
the username is stored in a keyChain and it goes back to the main viewController using: `self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

The data is loaded by a php file that use the username to get data from that username

And in the main viewController their is a tableView that contain the data

But the problem is that after the connection, the tableView does not change. It only change if i restart the app

My code to get the data:

```
@IBOutlet var tblTask: UITableView!

let bodyData = "username=" + username!

        let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "link to php file")
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            var output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            var array = self.JSONParseArray(output)

            for var i = 0, a = 1 ; i < array.count ; i += 2, a += 2 {

                if(a > 0 && i > 0)
                {
                    self.arrayDate.append(array[i])
                    self.arrayPoid.append(array[a])
                }
            }
            for var i = 0; i < self.arrayDate.count ; i++ {
                self.arrayPoid[i] += " livres"
            }


            self.tblTask.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Do you use UITableViewController? Did you bind the `tableView` outlet correctly?

Comment: Something is missing in your code. When do you perform `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest...` in your (table)ViewController? In which method?

Comment: So, each time you need to reload your tableView, outside of your `viewDidiLoad:`, you need in fact to call `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest...`. This will refetch your datasource and perform your tableView reload just after it. Do you agree with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think Unwind Segues are what you need. You can set them with only a few steps. Add this method in your rootViewController:

```
@IBAction func reset(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In Interface Builder, create `UIButtons` in any viewController that would need to go back to rootViewController. Then link each of these `UIButtons` to the red "Exit" button of their respective viewController and select reset: in the pop-up menu that appears (see the images below).

[image]

[image]

When you will click on those buttons, you will be brought back to your rooViewController and `reset:` will be performed (with your tableView reloaded).

See WWDC 2012 session video "Adopting Storyboards in Your App" for more details about unwind segues [starts at 38 minutes].

Comment: With that do i still need navigationController.popToRootView ? Cause it's giving me a error

Comment: No, I believe that you don't need `navigationController.popToRootView` anymore. Let me know.

Comment: No you don't need it but it still does not reload the data but i know it's calling the function cause i added a println in it

Comment: OK. Now, you just have to find a way to reload your tableview... Check your datasource and delegate. How do you manage your PHP file? It could be the problem.

Comment: I load the data using sendAsynchronousRequest maybe it's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the `UITableViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method. Does that solve it?